# Is the formula line tracking column insert properly in an org table?

Tags: org-table

I exhibit with a simple table.  My org version is
Org mode version 9.2.4 (9.2.4-10-g3b006f-elpa @ /Users/alanwehmann/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20190715/)

```
| 1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
| 5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |
#+TBLFM: @4$1=@-2::@4$2=@-2::@4$3=@-2::@4$4=@-2
```

insert a column using 'org-table-insert-column (don't update)

```
| 1 |   |  2 |  3 |  4 |
| 5 |   |  6 |  7 |  8 |
| 9 |   | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 5 |   |  6 |  7 |  8 |
#+TBLFM: @4$2=@-2::@4$3=@-2::@4$4=@-2::@4$5=@-2
```

There is now a formula for the blank column and no formula for the first column.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on 9.3.8. I suspect that it will go away if you upgrade to the latest version available from [Org ELPA](https://orgmode.org/elpa.html).

Comment: This was fixed by [this commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/fe34a408f24948ccbe936fdf734ba4110b957e3e).

Answer (score 1):

The problem goes away with version 9.4 of Org.